# Dapr Subscriber not working, not receiving data

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, dapr

I have implemented the Dapr Subscriber but it's not working and it's not receiving any data.

```
[Topic("pubSubName", "topicName")]
[HttpPost("/topicName")]
public ActionResult ProcessData([FromBody] string data)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Received data: {data}");
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue I was running the application on port 6000.

I have just removed the port from the below command and it's working as expected. Or you can use port 5000.

```
dapr run --app-id tradebookingconsumer --app-port 6000 dotnet run
```

**Correct Command:** `dapr run --app-id tradebookingconsumer dotnet run`

Comment: did you use external publisher or Dapr enabled publisher to get it working?

Comment: @MandarJogalekar what do you mean by external and dapr enabled publisher?

Comment: i mean publisher which does not follow dapr standard. like external mqtt broker

Comment: @MandarJogalekar I don't remember exactly. I think it was just a publisher

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. what I observed here

1. Application is running in one specific port:

   "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:**7006**",
2. but we run the "dapr" with different port, that might be issue.

   dapr run --app-id order-processor --resources-path ../../../components --app-port **7005** -- dotnet run

The ports are different 7006 and 7005, so due to this reason, order-process was not able to listening, when I run with the same port it was working fine for me.